# Integration SDK video ad Mobfox

Tags: android, eclipse, mobfox

Thank you for advance.
I use Mobfox integration SDK for video ads.
I get this error in eclipse :

****FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat;.checkSelfPermissionat com.mobfox.sdk.bannerads.Banner.getLocation(Banner.java:591)at com.mobfox.sdk.bannerads.Banner.init(Banner.java:332)at com.mobfox.sdk.bannerads.Banner.load(Banner.java:364)at com.mobfox.sdk.interstitialads.InterstitialAd.load(InterstitialAd.java:326)****

In the activity I can't put the Override method onRequestPermissionsResult because it's not recognizable.
But I have import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

In build.gradle : dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':MISDK:extras:google:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
    compile files('libs/MobFox-Android-SDK-Core-2.+.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22"

Now I changed the class and remove v4 lib but not working

what it's wrong? please, help me.